# Do Facebook page tabs have to be https? It doesn't seem like it

Tags: facebook, http, iframe, https

Why, if FB has stated that framed page tabs must be https, I can right-click on many of them, open in new window and see clearly that they are http? Are they just saying this and not enforcing it?
Example: 
http://apps.facebook.com/dousaflavor/

Comment: Go to https://apps.facebook.com/dousaflavor/ , and try again …

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include a HTTPS URL, users using Facebook over HTTPS won't be able to access your app

Comment: It accesses that one, even though the ssl is invalid.

Comment: And many users' browsers will fail to show any of the content because of the invalid certificate

Comment: So basically, Lays, a gigantic company, has a million dollar facebook app that is failing to load on many users' browsers. I find that hard to believe. I just wish there was some solid documentation on exactly how https pages will behave on facebook.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your comment, the app you linked to does support HTTPS and has a valid certificate on its HTTPS url - you asked what happens when a HTTPS url isnt supplied: http://i.imgur.com/MQyuH.png